# Limit the amount of invoice objects returned in NetSuite

Tags: c#, web-services, netsuite, invoice

I am working on an integration with a client's NetSuite account, which includes extracting invoice data in order to create a "first sales date" (first invoice created) and a "last sales date" (latest invoice created). My issue involves limiting the amount of invoices returned in the response, as there are currently about 265,000 invoice records in their system - hundreds of which can belong to one customer record. Is there a way to request only the two necessary invoice records for each customer?

Here is my current code in C#:

```
int invoiceCount = 0;

private void searchInvoices()
{
    // This operation requires a valid session 
    this.login(true);

    TransactionSearch transactionsSearch = new TransactionSearch();
    TransactionSearchBasic transactionSearchBasic = new TransactionSearchBasic();

    transactionSearchBasic.type = new SearchEnumMultiSelectField();
    transactionSearchBasic.type.@operator = SearchEnumMultiSelectFieldOperator.anyOf;
    transactionSearchBasic.type.operatorSpecified = true;
    transactionSearchBasic.type.searchValue = new string[] { "_invoice" };

    transactionsSearch.basic = transactionSearchBasic;

    SearchResult transactionResponse = _service.search(transactionsSearch);

    Invoice[] invoices = new Invoice[transactionResponse.totalRecords];

    if (transactionResponse.status.isSuccess)
    {
        if (transactionResponse.totalRecords > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= transactionResponse.totalPages; i++)
            {
                invoices = processTransactionSearchResponse(transactionResponse, invoices);

                if (transactionResponse.pageIndex < transactionResponse.totalPages)
                {
                    this.setPreferences();
                    this.login(true);
                    transactionResponse = _service.searchMoreWithId(transactionResponse.searchId, i + 1);

                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            _out.info("\nNothing found.");
        }
    }
}

private Invoice[] processTransactionSearchResponse(SearchResult transResult, Invoice[] invoices)
{
    Record[] transactionRecords = transResult.recordList;
    Invoice invoice = new Invoice();

    foreach (Record rec in transactionRecords)
    {
        invoice = (Invoice)rec;
        invoices[invoiceCount] = invoice;

        invoiceCount++;
    }

    return invoices;
}
```

Comment: I don't know much about web services, but from the interface you can define a search that has a column as the minimum of the invoice dates and another column the maximum of the invoice dates. You could set the search filter to filter to the customer internal ID. From glancing at the web service search operation, you'll need to use an advanced search instead of basic search to do this in this fashion.

Answer (score 0):

Is the totalRecords length 265k?

If so then you can't really say return me X records, but you can do something like filter by date.

Answer (score 0):

First create a search with all the clients and then make a foreach to get the invoices or play with trandate like this:

```
SearchDateField date = new SearchDateField();
date.@operator = SearchDateFieldOperator.before;
date.operatorSpecified = true;
date.searchValue = DateTime.Now.AddDays
```